Apex chart custom text on selection start and end points on line chart if brush:true
As I've integrated apex-chart in react project. I've added feature of drag and select section on graph on line chart, now I want to add selected min and max value at the boxes of selection box line as I've shown in image
version used:
 "apexcharts": "^3.49.1",
 "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",

Here is my code :
function App() {
    const chartRef = useRef(null);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState({
        chart: {
            id: "lineChart",
            zoom: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            brush: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            selection: {
                enabled: true,
                stroke: {
                    dashArray: 0,
                    opacity: 1,
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: true,
                        title: "TITLE",
                    },
                },
            },
            events: {
                selection: (chartContext, {
                    xaxis,
                    yaxis
                }) => {
                    console.log(
                        "DATE",
                        moment(xaxis.min).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a"),
                        moment(xaxis.max).format("DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss a")
                    );
                },
            },
        },
        stroke: {
            width: [1, 3],
            curve: ["straight", "monotoneCubic"],
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: false,
            x: {
                show: true,
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return moment(val).format("DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm A");
                },
            },
            y: {
                title: {
                    formatter: function (val, opt) {
                        return;
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        legend: {
            showForSingleSeries: true,
            markers: {
                radius: 0,
            },
            itemMargin: {
                horizontal: 4,
                vertical: 15,
            },
            offsetY: 10,
        },
        grid: {
            borderColor: "#CACACC",
            xaxis: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                },
            },
            yaxis: {
                lines: {
                    show: false,
                },
                labels: {},
            },
            padding: {
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 20,
            },
        },
        animations: {
            enabled: true,
            easing: "linear",
            dynamicAnimation: {
                speed: 1000,
            },
            toolbar: {
                show: true,
            },
        },
        xaxis: {
            type: "datetime",
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
            },
        },
        noData: {
            text: "No data available",
            align: "center",
            verticalAlign: "middle",
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        annotations: {
            xaxis: [],
        },
    });

    const series = [{
        name: "cl2",
        data: [{
                x: "2024-05-15T09:45:00.000Z",
                y: 1.8124996,
            },
            {
                x: "2024-05-15T10:00:00.000Z",
                y: 5.3385422,
            },
            {
                x: "2024-05-15T10:10:00.000Z",
                y: 0.5000003700000001,
            },
        ],
    }, ];

    return ( <
        >

        <
        div style = {
            {
                position: "relative"
            }
        } >
        <
        Chart options = {
            options
        }
        series = {
            series
        }
        type = "line"
        height = {
            350
        }
        ref = {
            chartRef
        }
        /> <
        /div> <
        />
    );
}
export default App;

I've tried to append text using css using this property:
<div data-employeename="Owner Joe" />
div:before {
  content: attr(data-employeename);
}

Any help is appreciate. Thank you.
